# jQuery-multiple show/hides and toggling fake links for "Read more..."

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I'm pretty good with HTML and CSS but when it comes to JavaScript - it just slips right off me. I've found great answers here but if it doesn't match exactly what I need I'm helpless to adapt it. Here's the project so far...

I have a group of articles with the classes “title_div story1”, “title_div story2”, “title_div story3”, etc.  The user only sees the first few lines of each.  The remainder of the lines in each article have the class “hidden_div”.  When user clicks anywhere on an article the hidden_div for that article is revealed with a "slideDown". Click again and the hidden_div is hidden again with "slideUp". Click on another article and the first article slides up while the new one slides down, and so on.

So far so good - except I found that many users don't click unless they are somehow alerted that there is more to see. So, to cue users, I added the text “Read more” at the end of the visible lines of each article.  I gave this text the class “faux-link” and styled it like a hyperlink.

The problem is that I want the text on the clicked article to toggle from “Read more” to “Read less” depending on the revealed state of the hidden_div.

I hope someone can help me finish what I've started here.

Here's the JavaScript I've been using and it works great except for that last little problem described above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".title_div").click(
        function () {
             var div = $(this).attr('rel');
             $(".hidden_div").slideUp("fast");
             if ($("#"+div).is(":hidden")) 
             {
                $("#"+div).slideDown("fast");
             } else {
                $("#"+div).slideUp("fast");
            }
       });
  });
</script>
```

~~~~~ Using info from Washington Guedes I made these changes but the "read less" remained if the article wasn't closed before another was opened...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

          <title>test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">
               </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
                {
                   $(".title_div").click(function()
                   {
                      var div = $(this).attr('rel');
                      div = $("#" + div);
                      $(".hidden_div").slideUp("fast");

                if (div.is(":hidden")) 
                  {
                      div.slideDown("fast");

                      $(".faux-link", this).html("Read less");
                      // : search for class "faux-link" in this ".title_div" context and change its html text.

                   } else {
                      div.slideUp("fast");
                      $(".faux-link", this).html("Read more");
                   }
                });
            });
          </script>

          <style type="text/css">
               .title_div {
                    margin-bottom: 6px;
                    margin-left: 24px;
                    width: 100%;
                    float: left;
                    background-color: #6CC;
               }
               .faux-link {
                    color: #233b92;
                    text-decoration: underline;
               }
          </style>

    </head>

    <body>
               <!-- Lorem story 1 -->
               <div class="title_div" rel="story1">
                    <h3>Story1</h3>
                         <p>Visible section of the profile article. </p>
                    <div id="story1" class="hidden_div" style=" display:none;">
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div1.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div1.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div1.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div1.</p>
                    </div><!-- /hidden story 1 -->
                    <p class="faux-link">Read more...</p> 
               </div><!-- /title-div 1 --> 

               <!-- Lorem story 2 -->
               <div class="title_div" rel="story2">
                    <h3>Story2</h3>
                        <p> Visible section of the profile article. </p>
                    <div id="story2" class="hidden_div" style=" display:none;">
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div2.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div2.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div2.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div2.</p>
                    </div><!-- /hidden story 2 -->
                    <p class="faux-link">Read more...</p> 
                </div><!-- /title-div 2 --> 

               <!-- Lorem story 3 -->
               <div class="title_div" rel="story3">
                    <h3>Story3</h3>
                        <p> Visible section of the profile article. </p>
                    <div id="story3" class="hidden_div" style=" display:none;">
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div3.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div3.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div3.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div3.</p>
                    </div><!-- /hidden story 3 -->
                    <p class="faux-link">Read more...</p> 
                </div><!-- /title-div 3 --> 

               <!-- Lorem story 4 -->
               <div class="title_div" rel="story4">
                    <h3>Story4</h3>
                        <p> Visible section of the profile article. </p>
                    <div id="story4" class="hidden_div" style=" display:none;">
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div4.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div4.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div4.</p>
                         <p>Inside the hidden_div4.</p>
                    </div><!-- /hidden story 4 -->
                    <p class="faux-link">Read more...</p> 
                </div><!-- /title-div 4 --> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/57x3qgs2/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".title_div").on("click", function(){
        var div = $(this).attr('rel');
        div = $("#" + div);
        $(".hidden_div").slideUp("fast");

        $(".faux-link").html("Read more");
        // : all "faux-link" get "Read more" text

        if (div.is(":hidden")) {
            div.slideDown("fast");

            $(".faux-link", this).html("Read less");
            // : only the "faux-link" of this ".title_div" get "Read less" text

        } else {
            div.slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: YES - faux-link is inside the title_div.  Thank you for that code but it didn't work. When I clicked on the text there was no change at all.  Could there be an adjustment?   I did experiment by taking your last 5 lines and it "almost" worked.(see code below)  When clicked the hidden_div was revealed and "read more" changed to "read less".  However if I clicked on the next article the first article slid up and "read less" remained.

Comment: @lucchesi609 I saw your point, I've edited for you: _http://jsfiddle.net/57x3qgs2/1/_

Comment: Exactly!  And thanks for the Fiddle. It alerted me to the fact that I need jquery-1.11 for this trick to work.  Thanks so much.